# Differences in binary values of an ascii char

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, binary, ascii

Lets take 'G' as an example, the letter 'G' is in the place #72.
using Python and the built-in method `ord('G')` I got 71.
Why the difference?

[image: ASCII TABLE]

Comment: Because the numbering starts from 0.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ (table showing what sk4x0r said)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the letter 'G' is in the place #72.

Your assumption is wrong. From your table, `G` is places at `0x47 = 71 = ord('G')`

The way to read your table is to, find the column number (`#Col`) and the row number(`#Row`) of the character you are searching, then the character code, in hex is `0x#Col#Row`

Comment: The first sentence in your answer could be worded differently. If you manually count the squares, starting from 1 as is natural for humans to do, `G` is in fact in the 72nd square, which I believe is what OP meant by "place #72", making the logic behind the assumption reasonably correct, but revealing a lack of understanding that it's just because ASCII values start at 0 that causes `0x47 == ord('G') == 71`